Is there a difference in the order of conditions in a python if statement?
Let's take the Leetcode problem, "first letter to appear twice" (https://leetcode.com/problems/first-letter-to-appear-twice/). The general solution that I came up with was to iterate over the string, store the values in a "seen" list, and if the next value is already in the "seen" list, then return that value.
So if I have some code that goes like this:
class Solution:
    def repeatedCharacter(self, s: str) -> str:
        seen = []
        for i in s:
            if i in seen:
                return i
            else:
                seen.append(i)
        

Is it any different (in terms of time or memory) to this:
class Solution:
    def repeatedCharacter(self, s: str) -> str:
        seen = []
        for i in s:
            if i not in seen:
                seen.append(i)
            else:
                return i
        

Is one way actually better/more efficient than the other, or is this just a preference of typing?

Which is better, 1+2 or 2+1 ?

It's the same in terms of efficiency. Probably is easier to read the first case, the if does not have a negation and the first option is the exit condition

Probably no difference.  But the more important thing to say is that premature optimization is a bad idea.  In this case, it is unlikely that any performance difference between the two versions will actually have a noticeable impact on the application you are using the code in.  Hence, optimizing it is futile.

This is not an answer to your question, but it would be more efficient to use a slice of s instead of creating seen.

In this particular case, there is no difference to performance or any other metric I am aware of, whether you put the negation in the if or the else... other than readability.
That said, in a general sense, the order of conditions in the if/elif/else structure can make a big difference.  Consider the following:
if some_expensive_function():
    # Code block to execute if some_expensive_function() resolves to 
    # a truthy** value
elif some_flag:
    # If some_expensive_function() is not truthy, some_flag will be evaluated 
    # and this code block will execute if its value is truthy
else:
    # This code will only be reached if both of the above conditions 
    # are not truthy.   

# ** Also a quick note about "truthy", as when I was a novice I didn't understand 
# that term, and I assume many who are or will be following may be experiencing 
# the same confusion right now while they're reading this:
# 
# When we say an expression or value is "truthy", we mean that it evaluates 
# to be equivalent to True.  This includes the overwhelmingly vast majority 
# of all possible values and references to any sort of objects, except for:
# 
#   - False (who'd have thought??)
#   - None
#   - the integer zero (0)
#   - and more or less all "empty" instances of iterable objects, including 
#     but not limited to: 
#       - the empty string: "" 
#       - the empty list: [] 
#       - the empty dict {}
#       - and so on, you should get the idea by now, this was not meant to be 
#         an exhaustive listing of all non-truthy values
# 
# ...all of which evaluate to False.  The way I think about it is this: 
#
# "Does my expression evaluate to one of the False-like values?"
#
# If the answer is no, then it is "truthy".  
#
# ...Okay, </tangent>

In this case, putting some_expensive_function() in the if at the beginning ensures it will always be executed/checked.  It would be much more efficient to reverse the order to this:
if some_flag:
    # Now this code block will get to execute if some_flag is truthy, 
    # without evaluating some_expensive_function first.  In this case,
    # we have saved the majority of the potential processing time/resources 
    # that are possible for this section of the code, since for each time 
    # that some_flag is true, we avoided having to ever execute the 
    # expensive function call. 
elif some_expensive_function():
    # This code will now execute only if some_flag resolves to False, 
    # and then some_expensive_function() shows itself to be truthy, as well.
else:
    # And same as before, this code will only be reached if both of the 
    # above conditions are not truthy.  

Because that way, the trivially inexpensive boolean flag check will come first, and if it resolves to True, some_expensive_function() will never be called at all, since if/elif/else structures check each condition from the top down until one is True, and then break out without executing the rest.  This means that your program will execute more efficiencly on average using this second form of the logic structure, how much so depending on the percentage of the time the trivial boolean flag resolves to True (and unless it is False all or nearly all of the time you will end up with some amount of efficiency improvement.  Why is that?  It is because checking an already evaluated value or expression in a variable for truthiness can be thought of as so close to taking no time at all that it is essentially the same thing, but some_expensive_function takes real, non-trivial processing resources, and in the first form, you are always executing it every time since it comes first, but in the second form, some percentage of the time, you never had to evaluate it at all, since the whole branching if/elif/else block is ski;pped out of after the first branch which is truthy is taken.
In general, whenever I am writing code (in any language) that has an if/else if branching structure, I think about this stuff... which of the conditions is most likely to be True the most often?  I'll put those before the ones that are less likely, so that the less likely to be True conditions will be pointlessly evaluated less often.  And if a condition is expensive (i.e., processing- or resource-intensive), I will generally put it as close to last as possible, even if it might generally evaluate to True more often than some other, cheaper conditions.
It is essentially instantaneous to execute a simple boolean, or number comparison, but sometimes you end up with something that takes a real amount of time; for example:
if max([ 
    project.calculate_weighting(
        record.get_underlying_data(), 
        project.get_current_weighting_scheme()
    )['max_weight'] for project in user.get_active_projects() 
]) >= 2.0:
# Do something, unimportant to this Github answer, to my app's users who have 
# gone ham on their weighting schemes for one or more of their projects, 
# those naughty monkeys 

Even if the above condition is True 90% of the time, it can be a signifiant time-saver to stick it after several simple boolean or arthmetical checks, since those simple checks cost essentially nothing.  You might ask yourself, "self, are there any scenarios in which we don't need to know the answer to this expensive condition?".  Brainstorm about it real quick... maybe your users could lack permissions necessary to even see the controls related to that piece of functionality, or maybe there is a checkbox to opt out; those arte just examples, for your app, it could be literally anything, but the point is, you should always be thinking about stuff like this.
The same principle applies to compound conditions:
if some_flag or some_expensive_function():
    # Code to execute if both the flag AND the function are truthy

The above will be much more efficient, on average, than the below:
if some_expensive_function() or some_flag:
    # Code to execute if both the flag AND the function are truthy

Why is that, you may be asking, since either way, they both have to be true?  Well, it's because when Python (and indeed most any language) is evaluating compound conditions, it will check each expression from left to right.  In order to be as efficient as possible, once it finds that one of the expressions is false, it stops checking the rest, since there is now no way that it could ever be true, since all of the expressions must be true in a compound AND condition.
Incidentally, this is the same line of thought that gives rise to elegant one-liner assignments such as:
instance = element or db.lookup_element(query)

The above replaces the explicit format, which is rather less Pythonic:
if element:
    instance = element
else:
    instance = db.lookup_element(query)

Exactly how and why this works is a thing that took me what seems now to be an inordinate amount of time to grasp; that is, assignment using logical ANDs or ORs.  So I'll explain that, too:
Let's look at just the logic condition part, ignoring the assignment for now:
element or db.lookup_element()

The Python interpreter gets to this, and says1, "okay I see an "or" keyword here.  Let's see, is "element" an upstanding object of integrity and trustworthiness?"  (i.e., is it truthy?)
(scenario #1) (python:) "Oh it is?  Cool, then I'm satisfied." (aka, it is truthy).

And it resolves this compound condition's value to be the value of the variable "element" (presumably an instance of a custom object class of some sort)

(scenario #2) (python:) "Nope, element's permanent record shows that it cheated on its Introduction to Conditional Logic Structures course final exam, not trusting that one with a 10 foot pole" (a.k.a. it is not truthy)2.

In this case, it considers the expression db.lookup_element(query).  Regardless of whether this second part is truthy or not, the result of the evaluation of the compound condition will end up being the result of evaluating db.lookup_element(query).  However, if we chained another "or " onto the expression, then if db.lookup_element(query) evaluated to false, it would be that new, third expression that would be the result of evaluating the compound condition.

The logical "and" doesn't work quite the same though.  When expressions are ANDed together, they are evaluated left to right, same as with "or"s.  But unlike with "or", where the "return" value is the resulting value from the evaluation of the first expression that resolves to a truthy value, with AND, the "return" value is one of the boolean literals, either True or False; it does not return any of the values that result from evaluating the expressions.  The other difference from how ORs are evaluated is that while in an OR, expressions are evaluated from left to right until the first one is found that is truthy, with ANDs, they are evaluated from left to right until the first one is found that is NOT truthy.
All of this gives us two things of value to learn.  We've learned that Python isn't really doing anything special when interpreting logical statements.  Like any other code, it is evaluating expressions and returning their values at runtime.  In fact, you can think of it as using the keywords and and or is essentially a shortcut for calling them as functions, something like this:
or(expression1, expression2, ..., expressionN) or more properly:

def or(*expressions):
    for expression in expressions:
        if expression:
            return expression
    return expression # Whatever the last value in the list is, will be assigned 
                      # to expression at the end, and if it hasn't returned yet, 
                      # that value will be returned

So you can think of the expression element or db.lookup_element(query) instead as what is perhaps more understandable: or(element, db.lookup_element(query)).  Given the above function definition, it should become evident, then, what is happening here:
if or(element, db.lookup_element(query)):
    # "if" statements are checking whether a value is truthy; here, whatever the "or" function returns is checked

And also evident what is happening here:
result = or(element, db.lookup_element(query))
# "result" ends up assigned as the value returned by the or function, which, according to the function definition above, will be either the first of the expressions passed in that is truthy (from left to right), or if none are truthy, it will be the last of the expressions

For and, you can think of it as:
def and(*expressions):
    for expression in expressions:
        if not expression: # If expression is not truthy
            return False
    return True  # If it didn't return False at some point, it's True
    # Either way, you can see that it can only return one of the 
    # boolean literals, True or False

...Aaaaaand that's enough.  I hope this has ben informative, some of this stuff really went over my head when I was much less experiuenced and it would havbe been great for me to have someone think to explain it in detail.  before that, I understood that some of this stuff worked, but it seemed like magical hand-waving to me, a thing to memorize, rather than to understand and so no longer have any need to memorize.
1 What, your Python interpreter doesn't talk to you?  What kind of interpreter doesn't talk to you?  I'd consider getting your money back.
2 Hey, life's a drag if you can't amuse yourself once in a while when you're spending entirely too much of your work day trying to improve your SO answers because you got completely sidetracked while trying to search for something else that is stumping you that you're supposed to be working on.

In your first example the 2 codes are not equivalent though, so relative efficiency is not relevant. If both some_expensive_function() and some_flag are true, in one case you execute do_some_code_branch1(), in the other you execute do_some_code_branch2()...

Okay, that's fair, and you're right.  It wasn't the point though, the point was to try to describe the considerations one might want to make when determining the order of conditions in their code.  The "do_some_code_branch" stuff is just meant as a placeholder

It finally occurred to me, more than half a year later, that I should edit my answer to remove the possible confusion you were referencing in your reply.  So I have done that now, thanks for pointing it out.

You can use the dis module to inspect the bytecode. The only difference here is that the two blocks swap position. Having said that, there may be a tiny difference depending which side of the branch is taken more often. That will depend on the input.
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(Solution)
Disassembly of repeatedCharacter:
  2           0 RESUME                   0

  3           2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 STORE_FAST               2 (seen)

  4           6 LOAD_FAST                1 (s)
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                31 (to 74)
             12 STORE_FAST               3 (i)

  5          14 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             16 LOAD_FAST                2 (seen)
             18 CONTAINS_OP              0
             20 POP_JUMP_FORWARD_IF_FALSE     4 (to 30)

  6          22 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             24 SWAP                     2
             26 POP_TOP
             28 RETURN_VALUE

  8     >>   30 LOAD_FAST                2 (seen)
             32 LOAD_METHOD              0 (append)
             54 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             56 PRECALL                  1
             60 CALL                     1
             70 POP_TOP
             72 JUMP_BACKWARD           32 (to 10)

  4     >>   74 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             76 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis(Solution2)
Disassembly of repeatedCharacter:
  2           0 RESUME                   0

  3           2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 STORE_FAST               2 (seen)

  4           6 LOAD_FAST                1 (s)
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                31 (to 74)
             12 STORE_FAST               3 (i)

  5          14 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             16 LOAD_FAST                2 (seen)
             18 CONTAINS_OP              1
             20 POP_JUMP_FORWARD_IF_FALSE    22 (to 66)

  6          22 LOAD_FAST                2 (seen)
             24 LOAD_METHOD              0 (append)
             46 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             48 PRECALL                  1
             52 CALL                     1
             62 POP_TOP
             64 JUMP_BACKWARD           28 (to 10)

  8     >>   66 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             68 SWAP                     2
             70 POP_TOP
             72 RETURN_VALUE

  4     >>   74 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             76 RETURN_VALUE

